# Develop with hiredis on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, redis, hiredis

Trying to use [hiredis](https://github.com/redis/hiredis) on Windows, building a normal c++ application to read from and write to redis. The problem is that hiredis does not officially support building on Windows. How can one build an application utilizing hiredis with c++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After lots of searches and tries I propose this method using CMake, although the information can be used to build with other build systems too.

Grab [Microsoft's open source redis project](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/Redis) and open project file `msvs\RedisServer.sln`

Build the project in desired configuration (debug, release, ...)

Create an environmental variable named `hiredis_ROOT` (Control Panel->System->Advanced System Settings->Environmental Variables) and set its value to the extracted redis folder

Create a cmake find module with the content below and put in project root under `cmake` folder with the name `Findhiredis.cmake`

```
# set search hint directories
set(
     hiredis_POSSIBLE_ROOT_PATHS
     $ENV{hiredis_ROOT}
     /usr/local
     /usr
)


# find hiredis include directory
# =================================================================================

find_path(
  hiredis_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAME          hiredis/hiredis.h
  HINTS         ${hiredis_POSSIBLE_ROOT_PATHS}
  PATH_SUFFIXES "include" "deps"
)

if(NOT hiredis_INCLUDE_DIR)
  message(STATUS "Checking for hiredis... no")
  message(STATUS "Could not find include path for hiredis, try setting hiredis_ROOT")
  return()
endif()


# find hiredis library
# =================================================================================

# library for debug builds
find_library(
  hiredis_LIBRARY_DEBUG
  NAMES          hiredis
  HINTS          ${hiredis_POSSIBLE_ROOT_PATHS}
  PATH_SUFFIXES  "msvs/x64/Debug"
  DOC            "hiredis library for debug builds"
)

# library for release builds
find_library(
  hiredis_LIBRARY_RELEASE
  NAMES          hiredis
  HINTS          ${hiredis_POSSIBLE_ROOT_PATHS}
  PATH_SUFFIXES  "msvs/x64/Release"
  DOC            "hiredis library for release builds"
)

# create library name for linking
set(hiredis_LIBRARY "")
if(hiredis_LIBRARY_DEBUG AND hiredis_LIBRARY_RELEASE)
  set(hiredis_LIBRARY "optimized;${hiredis_LIBRARY_RELEASE};debug;${hiredis_LIBRARY_DEBUG}")
elseif(hiredis_LIBRARY_DEBUG)
  set(hiredis_LIBRARY "${hiredis_LIBRARY_DEBUG}")
elseif(hiredis_LIBRARY_RELEASE)
  set(hiredis_LIBRARY "${hiredis_LIBRARY_RELEASE}")
endif()

# check the result
if(NOT hiredis_LIBRARY)
  message(STATUS "Checking for hiredis... no")
  message(STATUS "hiredis include directory: ${hiredis_INCLUDE_DIR}")
  message(STATUS "Could not find hiredis library")
  return()
endif()


# find hiredis' interop library
# =================================================================================

find_library(
  hiredis_interop_LIBRARY_DEBUG
  NAMES          Win32_Interop
  HINTS          ${hiredis_POSSIBLE_ROOT_PATHS}
  PATH_SUFFIXES  "msvs/x64/Debug"
  DOC            "Windows modified interop library for debug builds"
)

find_library(
  hiredis_interop_LIBRARY_RELEASE
  NAMES          Win32_Interop
  HINTS          ${hiredis_POSSIBLE_ROOT_PATHS}
  PATH_SUFFIXES  "msvs/x64/Release"
  DOC            "Windows modified interop library for release builds"
)

set(hiredis_interop_LIBRARY "")
if(hiredis_interop_LIBRARY_DEBUG AND hiredis_interop_LIBRARY_RELEASE)
  set(hiredis_interop_LIBRARY "optimized;${hiredis_interop_LIBRARY_RELEASE};debug;${hiredis_interop_LIBRARY_DEBUG}")
elseif(hiredis_interop_LIBRARY_DEBUG)
  set(hiredis_interop_LIBRARY "${hiredis_interop_LIBRARY_DEBUG}")
elseif(hiredis_interop_LIBRARY_RELEASE)
  set(hiredis_interop_LIBRARY "${hiredis_interop_LIBRARY_RELEASE}")
endif()

# check the result
if(NOT hiredis_interop_LIBRARY)
  message(STATUS "Checking for hiredis' interop... no")
  message(STATUS "hiredis include directory: ${hiredis_INCLUDE_DIR}")
  message(STATUS "Could not find hiredis interop library")
  return()
endif()


# Sum up libraries
# =================================================================================

set(Ws2_32_LIBRARY "optimized;Ws2_32;debug;Ws2_32")
set(
    hiredis_LIBRARIES

    ${hiredis_LIBRARY}
    ${hiredis_interop_LIBRARY}
    ${Ws2_32_LIBRARY}
)


# everything is found. just finish up
# =================================================================================

set(hiredis_FOUND TRUE CACHE BOOL "Whether hiredis is found on the system or not")
set(hiredis_INCLUDE_DIR ${hiredis_INCLUDE_DIR} CACHE PATH "hiredis include directory")
set(hiredis_LIBRARIES ${hiredis_LIBRARIES} CACHE FILEPATH "hiredis library for linking against")

message(STATUS "Checking for hiredis... yes")
```

include the find module in your top level `CMakeLists.txt` with this command:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(hiredis REQUIRED)
```

Set custom definitions, include paths and link libraries in your cmake project:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
include_directories(${hiredis_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(my-redis-application ${hiredis_LIBRARIES})
```

That's it. And you're done.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Did it. There's a problem I think in markdown formatting which did not let me insert the code while writing a list. Had to remove the list but forgot to insert the code.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer an alternative cpp library [bredis](https://github.com/basiliscos/cpp-bredis): it does not uses official redis parser (`hiredis` library), that's why it perfectly compiles on Windows (c++ 14).

*disclaimer: I'm the author of bredis*